# How do I get the list of changed and added files since the creation of a branch in git by a specific author?

Tags: git

I may have introduced errors in one of my commits. My branch has been merged with master several times. What I need to do is to copy all of the files I created or changed since the branch began to a temp directory, delete the branch, branch off master again, and copy back my files.

Answer (score 1):

You can look through the Git log for commits done specifically by yourself. Git whatchanged will show you the files modified in every commit. If you want to specify a range of commits (back to the creation of your branch), specify a revision range or use the --since flag.

```
git whatchanged --author YOUR_EMAIL_HERE --since="1 month ago"
```